# Internet Explorer 10 sporadic issues working with Remote Data Services

Tags: vbscript, internet-explorer-10

We have a classic ASP application that uses RDS (remote data services).  We have users all over hitting this web application in IE6 - IE9 flawlessly and have been for years and years.  With IE10 on Win 7 64 bit machines, they are experiencing sporadic slow times that are impossible to replicate.

This can happen anywhere in the application, whether it's a small or large call... and it's completely random.  For example, I can make the same call X times in a row, then all of the sudden that X+1 call just hangs, sometimes IE stops responding.  If it does eventually free up, I can make the same call many more times like nothing has happened.

Tried thus far:

- Checked all IE settings to make sure they are the same as our other IE versions.
- Increase temporary internet files storage.
- Made sure users were not using a proxy server.
- Tried both 32 and 64 bit IE10.
- Watched the sql calls in profiler and it appears the sql was returned just as fast as the   previous times it did not lock up.
- Had the user revert back to IE9 (on a different machine) doing the same job, no issues found.

Does anyone know of issues with IE10 64 bit and RDS or have a clue how to troubleshoot further?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT (Adding code snippet):

```
Function GetErrorRS()
   dim sDate, eDate
    Set oADS = CreateObject("RDS.DataSpace")
    Set Obj = oADS.CreateObject("ErrorLog.busErrorLog", strIEServer)
    Window.Status = "Loading Error data, please wait ..."
    Result = Obj.ReadErrorLog(UserName,TheErrNumber,sDate,eDate,rsErrors,strUserID,strDBServer,strDBName,strError)
    Window.Status = "Done"
    if result = 0 then
        GetErrorRS = True
    else
        GetErrorRS = False
        MsgBox strError
    end If
End Function
```

Comment: Could you post the code that causes the slowdown? If it's an ASP server-side code, it shouldn't really matter which browser is used, techically IE10 should affect only client-side code.

Comment: Code same added, thanks for looking!

Comment: But this is not server-side ASP code, correct? It looks like VB Script code that runs in the client browser.

Comment: Correct, this is client side VBScript.  The Window.Status gets set to "Loading Error data, please wait ...", we get the browser freeze at that point so that leads me to believe it's something with RDS.  When/if it unfreezes, we do get the "Done" in the status bar.  

Of course, most of the time it's working just fine and in every other browser we don't hit this random slow time.  Isn't troubleshooting sporadic issue fun? :-)

Comment: Been there. So does the call actually execute correctly after freeze and just takes a very long time? Does putting browser into compatibility mode help?

Comment: The call does actually execute after a long wait, for example a <1 second call taking 1.5 minutes (sql profiler showing <1 second sql statement during that time as normal).  Other times, it does completely lock the browse, as in browser not responding, and it does not complete... we have to kill the process.